# Font Family not working in my project?

Tags: android, font-family

Recently I converted my eclipse project to the android studio after that I update all SDK 26.
I tried custom font using font family in my project XML it's showing correctly.
But when I run the project and seeing in mobile it's not updating.

please help me.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xx.xxx.xx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}

sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 
'src/main/res/assets/'] } }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile project(':xxx')

compile project(':xxxxx')

compile project(':xxxx')

compile project(':xxxxxx')

compile project(':xxxxx')

compile project(':xxxxxx')

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.6'

compile files('libs/AppMeasurement_Android.jar')

compile files('libs/commons-io-2.1.jar')


compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')

/* compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.5.jar')

 compile files('libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.5.jar')*/

//compile files('libs/json-path-0.8.0.jar')

compile files('libs/json-smart-1.1.jar')

//compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')

//compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4'

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:`enter code here`constraint-
layout:1.0.2'


}
```

Comment: we need to see your code

Comment: Please check my manifest

Answer (score 0):

1. First Create Directory in your project called "font"
2. Copy the font file (.ttf) into that directory
3. Now into your ui components add this

Here is textview

```
<TextView 
 android:fontFamily="@font/your_font"
 android:text="Font is working"/>
```

Hope this will work

Comment: I am already using what you mentioned in the above.Its not working

Comment: Add xml file to the question